# How to solve 2 different Facebook accounts login chrome driver with Selenium C# (windows form)?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have 2 different Facebook accounts need to be login (I am trying to learn selenium). Somebody helps me to use the loop of for or the commands of array with listviewtextbox (listviewtextbox contains the Facebookemail and Facebookpass to login). Thanks for all!!

```
Chromedriver driver, driver1;
driver = new chrome driver(services, options);  //services and options all created
driver1 = new chrome driver(services, options);
driver.Url = "https://facebook.com/login";
driver1.Url = "https://facebook.com/login";
driver.Navigate();
driver1.Navigate();

public void Login()
{
   driver.FindElenment(By.ID("email")).SendKeys("aaa");
   driver1.FindElenment(By.ID("email")).SendKeys("bbb");
   driver.FindElenment(By.ID("pass")).SendKeys("aaa");
   driver1.FindElenment(By.ID("pass")).SendKeys("bbb");
   driver.FindElenment(By.Name("login")).Click();
   driver1.FindElenment(By.Name("login")).Click();
}
```